# How do I get a timer to change a picture?

Tags: java, swing, timer

How do I get an image to change after a Swing timer is done? I know it plays the code in the actionPerformed class when it's done, but I could not get it to work.

I have the image painted using the paint method if that changes anything :)

```
public class Sprite extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

private Board board;
private Timer timer;


public Sprite() {

    timer = new Timer(1000, this);
    grow=false;


}
public Image grow() {
    if(grow) 
         return image;
    else
         return other_image;
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    grow = false;
    board.repaint();
}
```

**EDIT** The code is something along the lines of this ^^

Comment: Agree with Sja91. Without code it's impossible to tell what you're doing wrong. All we can give are general suggestions such as "change the Icon displayed by a JLabel", but if you're going to want more than that, you really need to give us more as well.

Comment: Who calls grow ? When ?

Comment: Regarding your posted code, please read Jon Skeet's blog, [Writing the Perfect Question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx), especially the section on **Sample code and data**. We would be best served if the code you posted compiled and ran and made sense but is as short as possible. Your current code does not explain to us why you're having your problem, so why not post code that we can run that **shows** us your problem?

Comment: @P. Lalonde: a different class, I already have that part figured out and I'm positive it works.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: I'm not really asking you to solve a problem, I'm asking you to explain to me a good way to change an image using a timer. Whether that be a link to a tutorial, or an example I really don't care.

Comment: @alexdr3437: As I mentioned previously. You can have the Timer swap the Icon displayed by a JLabel, but the devil's in the details which again depends on your code and what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: "I have the image painted using the paint method if that changes anything"

Comment: @alexdr3437: probably better if you don't. Use ImageIcons and swap them instead. It's a lot cleaner and easier.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: The images are moving so I need to be able to set the location myself.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: That worked.....now I just feel stupid :(

Comment: @alexdr3437 Welcome to my world :D

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment so I will just say it here and edit when you answer, What is your code like so far? what have you tried ? there are quite a few ways to achieve what you want, but your question is sort of lacking detail.

edit:
You arn't showing a field named grow, and it isn't a good idea to have a field/variable by the name of grow and have a method named grow.

One thing you can do according to yours would be something like.

```
public class Sprite extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    public boolean Grown;
    public Board board; // never set in your example, 
                        // nor do i have any idea what it is for
    public Timer timer;
    public BufferedImage UngrownImage; // Initialize these images yourself
    public BufferedImage GrownImage;    

    public sprite() {

        Grown = false;
        timer = new Timer(1000, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        Grown = true;
        board.repaint(); // you may want to call super.repaint() too
                         // but again I do not know what board is.
    }

    // unless your "Board" is taking care of it, here you can paint the images
    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        super.paint(g);

        int imgX = 0, imgY = 0;

        if(Grown && GrownImage != null)
            g.drawImage(GrownImage, imgX, imgY, null);
        else if(UngrownImage != null)
            g.drawImage(UngrownImage, imgX, imgY, null);
        else
            System.out.println("error: No images loaded");

    }
}
```

If there is anything you do not understand let me know, I will gladly summarize it to you, I assumed that all this is stuff you have worked with, judging off of what you are trying to do.

Comment: when the timer is done it changes a boolean to false. When this boolean is false I know for sure that it changes the picture because I can do it manually, but for some reason when it was changed using the timer it does not work. If you need me to post the code I can.

Comment: @alexdr3437: re, "if you need me to post the code..." I guess my comment to your main question was written in invisible cyber ink.

Comment: I wrote that comment before I saw yours, the code is posted now

Comment: There are several significant problems with this code. You should not paint directly in a JFrame as you risk painting errors with the JFrame's children and its borders. Instead you should paint in a JComponent such as a JPanel and in its paintComponent.

Comment: As long as you call super.paint(g) first, Then there is no problem, I have been using this for many years for simpler things, Though recently I switched to using Canvas for other reasons, amongst those the main reason was buffering. Without clear context of his goal I saw no need for buffering.

Comment: @Sja91 : Swing uses [Double Buffering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/doublebuf.html) by default in many of its components. No need to use a Canvas, which belongs to AWT. Not a good approach, I must say.

Comment: ah , nIce this is true, But i use AWT not swing, which is why i use canvas to double buffer, that, and if i want a drawing area of exactly say, 800x640, then i set my canvas's size and the window stretches around it, no guessing about setting window size to 800x640 + borders and title bar and sometimes footer.

Answer (score 1):

Better to use a JLabel to display the Images as ImageIcons and simply have the Timer swap your images. I can post a sample program such as this one:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TimerImageSwapper {
   public static final String[] IMAGE_URLS = {
      "http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/d7000/img/sample/img_01.png",
      "http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/d7000/img/sample/img_02.png",
      "http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/d7000/img/sample/img_04.png",
      "http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/d3200/img/sample/img_08.png",
      "http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/d3200/img/sample/img_05.png",
      "http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/d3200/img/sample/img_01.png",
      "http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/d3200/img/sample/img_06.png"
      };

   private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 1000;

   private ImageIcon[] icons = new ImageIcon[IMAGE_URLS.length];
   private JLabel mainLabel = new JLabel();

   private int iconIndex = 0;;

   public TimerImageSwapper() throws IOException {
      for (int i = 0; i < icons.length; i++) {
         URL imgUrl = new URL(IMAGE_URLS[i]);
         BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(imgUrl);
         icons[i] = new ImageIcon(image);
      }

      mainLabel.setIcon(icons[iconIndex ]);

      new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new ActionListener() {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            iconIndex++;
            iconIndex %= IMAGE_URLS.length;
            mainLabel.setIcon(icons[iconIndex]);
         }
      }).start();
   }

   public Component getMainComponent() {
      return mainLabel;
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      TimerImageSwapper timerImageSwapper;
      try {
         timerImageSwapper = new TimerImageSwapper();
         JFrame frame = new JFrame("Timer Image Swapper");
         frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         frame.getContentPane().add(timerImageSwapper.getMainComponent());
         frame.pack();
         frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
         frame.setVisible(true);

      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         System.exit(-1);
      }

   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

But again without knowing the structure of your program, it will be hard to know if this will help you.

Comment: I guess you didnt see my comment on the main post. The solution was just some stupid mistake. Sorry for wasting your time :)

Comment: @alexdr3437: at least run my code to how to use JLabels to swap images. That's the least you can do. And next time, please don't waste our time like this: read the Jon Skeet link I have provided in my comments above and post pertinent compilable and runnable code. Don't force folks to guess what *might* be wrong.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels : I liked this logic thingy, using % and all :-). +1 for this nicely crafted example.